# ¿Como obtener datos de la segunda Key generada en Firebase?

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase, firebase-snapshot

Junto con saludar, tengo una duda respecto a la pregunta, quisiera poder obtener los datos que están marcados en amarillo para luego mostrarlo en un recyclerView de Android Studio, pero no sé como obtener la Key que se genera aleatoriamente con el push() que está marcado en rojo.

He visto varios videos, tutoriales y documentación, pero lo que más he logrado ha sido mostrar los datos marcados en verde.

[image: Imagen referente a Key y los respectivos colores]

El codigo donde lo que más logré mostrar fue lo marcado en verde

```
public class mostrarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerPa;
DatabaseReference database;
Adapter adapter;
ArrayList<Pacientes> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrar);

    recyclerPa = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerPa);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Usuarios");
    recyclerPa.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerPa.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new Adapter(this,list);
    recyclerPa.setAdapter(adapter);

    database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                Pacientes pacientes = dataSnapshot.getValue(Pacientes.class);
                list.add(pacientes);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SOes! Sadly, this is a Spanish-only site, so you must translate the whole question to Spanish, including the title. (You can also move it to English version of SO, but we can try here!). Also, code goes as text, not as images (can't replicate from an image)

Comment: Ooh lo siento, se me pasó por alto el "es." trasladaré la pregunta! gracias y veré lo del código también

Comment: Eres libre de darnos la oportunidá de ayudar si la traduces :D

Comment: Gracias!! ahí la transcribí a español pero en 40m aproximados la postearé, debido a que está en margen de que debo esperar para publicar, gracias denuevo y ojalá me puedan ayudar, intenté varios caminos pero aquí estamos!! jaja

Comment: Puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/498326/edit) ESTA pregunta para dejarla en español y con el código como texto. Sin tiempo de espera...

Comment: No me sabía esa! jaja ahí lo hice!

Answer (score 1):

Justo hace poco me tope con el mismo dilema y me pareció super conveniente tu pregunta porque casi tengo la misma estructura de base de datos, incluso me hice una cuenta para poder seguir tu pregunta jejé

Los datos no se logran obtener porque el método ***addValueEventListener*** se llama cada que se modifican datos en la referencia de la base de datos especificada, incluidos los cambios realizados a los elementos secundarios por lo que crearía un **Snapshot** muy grande al cual permanecer al escucha. Incluso obteniendo la **pushKey** no me permitía obtener el objeto/datos que tenía por debajo de ella, ni al hacer la consulta una sola vez con ***get().addOnSuccessListener*** o ***addListenerForSingleValueEvent***.

Y en la documentación de Firebase dice que adjuntes solo el nivel más alto necesario para observar/leer los cambios.

La solución que encontré fue obtener la **pushKey** y con esta realizar otra consulta especificando más la referencia a la base de datos. No estoy segura si sea la mejor forma de hacerlo, soy nueva utilizando Firebase, así que corríjanme si me equivoco, por favor.

```
String pushKey = "";
database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
            Pacientes pacientes = dataSnapshot.getValue(Pacientes.class);
            list.add(pacientes);
            for (DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                pushKey =  data.getKey().toString();
                /*Obteniendo la pushkey puedes retornarla o directamente 
                 *asignarla a una variable global (dependiendo de como estés 
                 *trabajando con los datos) para realizar la nueva consulta con 
                 *una referencia más específica a la base de datos.*/
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        /*Verificar si aquí se tiene que mandar llamar al adpatador por 
         *si le faltan los datos de la nueva consulta*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
//La nueva referencia quedaría algo así:
DatabaseReference newReference = database.child("Paciente").child(pushKey);
/*Y con esta nueva referencia puedes hacer la nueva consulta para 
 *obtener los datos que tienes marcados en amarillo, con el método que 
 *creas más conveniente.*/
newReference.addValueEventListener...
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda c:

Comment: Gracias por pasar! la comprobaré apenas pueda, pero luego de leer harto la documentación (También estoy modo nuevo en lo mismo) me decanté con sacar "Pacientes" de Usuarios, y si quiero buscar un paciente termino haciendo referencia a "Pacientes" en ves de a "Usuarios", la manera de diferenciar pacientes fue usando el Rut, algo como "userID+rut" donde userID es la ID de 'FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()', también puedes ver estos videos muy buenos! [enlace](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) Cualquier cosa me dices, andamos igual! jaja

Comment: Qué bueno c: se escucha más sencillo, muchas gracias por lo vídeos ya los veré, igualmente cualquier cosa aquí estamos